# Not able to record events for karaf service using Java flight recorder(JFR) in JMC

Tags: karaf, jmc

I'm getting message like `"this flight recording has no recording settings events"` while recording events for karaf service.

Can any one please help me for this issue. I put the setting in service script under `Karaf Arugs`: like

```
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures
-XX:+FlightRecorder
```

Comment: Do you get this when creating the recording or when trying to view it in JMC?

Comment: when I am  trying to view the JFR file in JMC

Comment: Do you get any other data in the recording, or are the tabs empty? How did you create the recording?

Comment: We are not getting any recorded information. But the JVM version info is getting published.

Comment: Are you using a JDK version lower than 7u40?

Comment: No..
i'm using java version "1.7.0_71" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: In karaf service i'm using  java version "1.7.0_71" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14) and i'm trying to open the jfr file in in windows and  java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)

Comment: I creating  the setting in service script under Karaf_Opts: like -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder and i am recording with command "jcmd <PID> JFR.start duration=120s filename=myrecording.jfr"

Comment: Potentially this is related to Karaf running as a Windows Service. Can you running it as a normal application and see if it makes any difference, and I will try to hunt down the reason for the service problems.

Comment: Karaf is running on linux server and i'm trying to recaord the events of karaf using jcmd commands.

Comment: Ah, I see. Could you try adding the following JVM flag to your karaf, and check which flightrecorder output you get: -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=loglevel=info

Comment: I've now spoken to the people who work on the JFR implementation (I work on JMC). The theory is that your JVM either cannot access, or cannot parse the JDK/lib/jfr/*.jfc files. In the cannot parse case, it might be that the Karaf uses a custom XML parser that is unable to parse the jfc files, so you can try to set this property: -Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl        In the cannot access the jfc files case, try running with the loglevel flag in my comment above and see if you get any interesting output.

Comment: I'm asking the obvious because it's what happened to me to cause the above error.  Where does your "java" command point?  I ran into this issue, even after installing the latest JDK 1.8 because my "java" command was still pointing to a JRE from before Flight Recorder existed.